# What's wrong with these seemingly perfect ML model?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, classification

I wanted to find an optimal model to solve the assigned classification problem. Everything went smooth before I applied pd.get_dummies() function to preprocess the data. The experiment showed a impossibly perfect result. I know it is unlikely to happen but I do not know why. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Code for preprocessing data is as below

```
# Encoding Booking Status
status_dict = {'Not_Canceled':1, 'Canceled':0}
df.booking_status = df.booking_status.map(status_dict)
df.drop('Booking_ID',axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.dropna()
df = pd.get_dummies(df)

# Standardizing Data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
X = df.iloc[:,0:-1]
y = df.iloc[:,-1]
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X)
rescaledX = scaler.transform(X)
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(rescaledX[0:5,:])
```

And I split my data into training and testing with a proportion of 0.3

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(rescaledX, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=15)
```

I used several models and the amazing result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQfSW.png)

Simple code, stupid me. By the way, just a beginner in ML field. Any advice to master it well?

Comment: Many reasons why you may have high results. One reason is that the data set may not be varied much such that testing and train data are the exact same even though you did a test-train split.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by data leaks. You must split your data first before any data pre-processing step. For example,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(rescaledX, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=15)
```

Then do your data scaling part on the training and test data separately.

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
rescaledX = scaler.transform(X_train)
```

You could try to use Pipe line as well to avoid data leaks.

```
# correct data preparation for model evaluation with k-fold cross-validation
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
# define dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, n_informative=15, n_redundant=5, random_state=7)
# define the pipeline
steps = list()
steps.append(('scaler', MinMaxScaler()))
steps.append(('model', LogisticRegression()))
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)
# define the evaluation procedure
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
# evaluate the model using cross-validation
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
# report performance
print('Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores)*100, std(scores)*100))
```

Ref: https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-preparation-without-data-leakage/